# SPA на Vue + Laravel: Сессии и CSRF токен

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookie, laravel5, vue-router

Пишу приложение, Laravel используется для API на JWT токенах. В web всего один route, который собственно возвращает каркас веб-страницы, а сама маршрутизация реализована на фронте.

Я в Laravel совсем новичок, возник вопрос где отключить CSRF защиту и laravel сессии? И главное, что вообще laravel сует в куки из коробки, что не понадобится для API?

Comment: Отличная статья https://medium.com/@shindelav/make-an-api-based-application-with-laravel-passport-d6f1074a7b3a

Comment: Так апи роуты сразу без CSRF защиты

Comment: @Walfter Спасибо, я уже разобрался с посредниками.Там дело в том, что основной роут в web же лежит, на него CSRF защита распространяется